# ParameterNotFound: missing dependency on using staticphp as mapping-type in DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: php, symfony, mapping, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I try to use `staticphp` as mapping type as it is described in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-bundle/en/4.3/config.html#mapping-configuration), but as soon as I update my config from `annotation` into `staticphp` I get an error saying, that the driver is missing a service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.metadata.staticphp.class":

> ParameterNotFoundException HTTP 500 Internal Server Error The service
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_staticphp_metadata_driver" has a
> dependency on a non-existent parameter
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.metadata.staticphp.class". Did you mean one of
> these: "doctrine.orm.metadata.php.class",
> "doctrine.orm.metadata.staticphp.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.configuration.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_manager.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.cache.array.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.cache.apc.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.cache.apcu.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.cache.memcache.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.cache.xcache.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.metadata.driver_chain.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.metadata.annotation.class",
> "doctrine_mongodb.odm.metadata.xml.class"?

By browsing the vendor files manually I also can't find any driver except of the xml-one and the default-annotation-driver inside the odm-package at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: The mapping driver is located in the `doctrine/persistence` library. It seems the `staticphp` service class declaration is missing in the doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle config, since the `symfony/doctrine-bridge` is what handles loading that extension driver service for the ORM and ODM. I suggest manually deleting the `var/cache/<env>` directory and then running `bin/console cache:warmup` to see if it is a wiring conflict.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I can, sounds promising though!